# Context getResources(), can't find resource

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to write a class which is to handle the maps methods (showmap, addmarker, etc) and I call these methods in an Activity or Fragment, but I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

I know what it means, but I canit solve it.
So I hope somebody can help me.

Here is the map calss:

```
public class MapHandle extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
private GoogleMap map;


public void initMap() {


    mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    if (mapFragment != null) {
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
                createMap(map);
            }
        });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error - Map Fragment was null!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}

public void createMap(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;
    if (map != null) {
        // Map is ready
        Toast.makeText(this, "Map Fragment was loaded properly!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error - Map was null!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

And here I call it in an Activity:

```
public class FragOne extends Fragment {

MapHandle mh;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mh = new MapHandle();
    mh.initMap();
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1,container,false);
}
}
```

Comment: Please show more of the stacktrace

Comment: Does `MapHandle` have its own layout? Do you ever open this activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this

```
mh = new MapHandle();
```

The Context becomes null since this is now an un-managed Activity.

You can use `onAttach(Context context)` and cast the context to get a reference to the parent Activity.

Alternatively, `FragOne` does not seem to serve any purpose than loading a Map, so have `FragOne` load and display the map itself (e.g. `extends SupportMapFragment`)

And, as commented below, `MapHandle` seems to not need to be an Activity. Primarily because you have not implemented `onCreate`, which is where you would otherwise be calling `initMap`

Comment: Also there is no point in `MapHandle` extending `AppCompatActivity` as its is only being used to create Abstraction for `Map` and `Location`.
Instead of extending to `AppCompatActivity` Bbeni should pass the required objects for ex. `Context`, `FragmentManager`